# In Ruby/Sinatra, Datamapper's .all works but .get doesn't?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, ruby-datamapper

I am trying to take data from a path in Sinatra, and use it to look up a particular record using Datamapper. The Datamapper [**docs**](http://datamapper.org/docs/find.html)  seem to indicate that.

```
get "/test/:test_path" do
    test_get = Intake.get( params[:test_path] )
    # Do stuff
    erb :blah_blah_blah
end
```

should find any records associated with the symbol :`test_path`

This does not work. test_get gets nil.

Meanwhile, what does work is

```
get "/test/:test_path" do
    test_all = Intake.all(:test_path => params[:test_path] )
    # Do stuff
    erb :blah_blah
end
```

My two questions are:

1. What am I doing wrong with the .get() call in Datamapper?
2. Is the .all(:name => value) method slower than .get(), or does it not matter which I use?

Here's a Sinatra script pared down to demonstrate the behavior.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'dm-core'
require 'dm-timestamps'

DataMapper.setup(:default, {:adapter => 'yaml', :path => 'db'})

class Intake
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,         Serial
  property :created_at, DateTime
  property :test_path,  String
end

get "/test/:test_path" do

  test_all = Intake.all(:test_path => params[:test_path] )
  puts 'test_all:' test_all.inspect

  test_get = Intake.get( params[:test_path] )
  puts 'test_get:' test_get.inspect

  "Hello World!"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`#get` only does a lookup based on primary key, with is the `id`. So

```
Intake.get(params[:test_path])
```

looks for something with id `params[:test_path]`, which will fail. Use

```
Intake.first(test_path: params[:test_path])
```

Comment: Many thanks. I misunderstood the Datamapper docs. (I edited the .first code to include the '=>'.)

Comment: Welcome to the 1.9 hash syntax.